# Duplicated function names when using Qt's dumpcpp

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2013

I use Qt5's dumpcpp tool to generate word.h and word.cpp. And my Qt project also include some windows file headers such as windows.h and setupapi.h, these file may include winuser.h. The problem is, in winuser.h there is a function macro called "ExitWindows" and in my generated word.h, there is a function in Word::Task class, also called "ExitWindows". The result is VS2013 throw a warning:

> warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'ExitWindows'

and an error following:

> error C2059: syntax error : ...

The waring and the error point to the same line. So I guess the reason is they have same name.

Is there a elegant method to solve this problem?

### Update

There also another conflicted function 'Word::ColorFormat.RGB()', which also a macro defined in wingdi.h.

Comment: I use dumpcpp in .pro file like TYPELIBS = $$ourcom.dll Then I include generate header like #define QAX_DUMPCPP_MSTSCLIB_NOINLINES
 #include "ourcom.h" Then at the bottom of that file that has the include above there is another include #include "ourcom.cpp" which contains all the classes I need. Without doing all that I could not manage all the errors caused by buggy dumpcpp tool. We basically need that ourcom_impl.cpp to selectively enable only needed and correct classes/methods there.

Comment: The article you might be interested in https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-28383

Comment: My workround for this is to comment out the dumped methods, because I don't use them for now. Its not so *elegant* but just *quick and dirty*,.